# Sending and receiving data PHP to android JAVA

Tags: java, php, android

I am currently working on an app for Android that receives data from server.
The problem that I do not really know how to make the data-transfer to the server and back to the app, I use PHP like an engine that accepts and returns data, but I'm not sure how good and effective it is.. Does anyone know how WAZE works and can give me a direction to my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use Web Service for that .

**A Web service is a method of communication between two electronic devices over the Web**

Look at this below project link.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/267023/Send-and-receive-json-between-android-and-php

Answer (score 0):

you need webservices to transfer your data on network.The W3C defines a "Web service" as "a software system designed to support interoperable machine-to-machine interaction over a network". [chk this](http://davidwalsh.name/web-service-php-mysql-xml-json)